# Karate match fails if the order of data elements is different

Tags: karate

I'm trying to validate an Xml response where one parent element has multiple child elements with the same tags but different text content like so:

```
Scenario: test  
      Given def expectation = <parent><child>1</child><child>2</child</parent>  
      And def reality = <parent><child>2</child><child>1</child></parent>  
      Then match reality == expectation
```

Karate is supposed to not be affected by the order of data elements but this scenario fails. Is this a bug or am I overlooking something?

I know I could probably get away with using "match contains" for each of the child nodes but I'm actually trying to validate a much more complicated response.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, maybe this can be better explained if you convert the XML to JSON:

```
* json expect = expectation
* print json
```

Which gives you:

```
{
  "parent": {
    "child": [
      "1",
      "2"
    ]
  }
}
```

And the other json would be:

```
{
  "parent": {
    "child": [
      "2",
      "1"
    ]
  }
}
```

So you see the problem right, they are not equal, and you have to get into `contains` and all that.

```
Then match expectation/parent/child contains $reality/parent/child
```

If your XML is relatively free of attribute complexity, you may be able to do some crazy things when you convert to JSON:

```
* def children = ['1', '2']
* def expected = { parent: { child: '#(^^children)' } }
* json actual = reality
* match actual == expected
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Obviously I see the difference. But as far as i know, lists could be considered at least equivalent if not equal even if the order of elements isn't. So I thought since this must be a common enough problem (i can anticipate the elements the list must comprise but the list might or might not be jumbled up) there might be a way to validate the entire response in one fell swoop. Using "contains" will work though, thank you!

Comment: @sophie yeah I hear you. lists are stricter than maps of key:values though

Answer (score 2):

I think if the array of data has to be matched properly you should provide the parent node of that array (which can be of any order) as an input to the match.

```
Then match reality.parent[*] == expectation.parent[*]
```

You mentioned that you have to validate a much more complicated response, I would suggest you break them into logical validation steps and use appropriate validation conditions.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't think this will work though. When I try your idea, an exception is thrown. Maybe because wildcards are not supported on the left hand side of a match statement?

Comment: @sophie it should be `$expectation.parent[*]` on the RHS

Comment: @PeterThomas Yes, that does work. It's not a solution for the initial problem though. And "match expectation == reality" works just as well (working in the sense that it produced the same fail result). Thanks again for answering so quickly, that's awesome.